# How can I test file download if download failed or success and keep downloading until success?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

First time when downloading the TimeDate.Now is for example 15:57 so I RoundDown make 15:55 format it and try to download it.

If no success in the completed event I'm trying to round it again from 15:55 to 15:50 formatting again and trying to download again.

The problem is that it's not rounding down again. In the completed event if there is error this line :

```
 current = RoundDown(current, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-5));
```

It's still the rounded 15:55 from the above and I want that until the download is not success keep round down and try to download the new currentLink with the new rounded down.  15:50 not success make it 15:45 not success 15:40 and so on round down and build the currentLink over and over again until the download is success.

```
public void GetImages()
        {
            defaultlink = "https://IMSRadar/IMSRadar_";

            current = RoundDown(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-5));
            var ct = current.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
            currentLink = defaultlink + ct + ".gif";

            using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                wc.DownloadFileCompleted += Wc_DownloadFileCompleted;
                wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(currentLink), @"d:\test.gif");
            }
        }

        private void Wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
                {
                    current = RoundDown(current, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-5));
                    var ct = current.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
                    currentLink = defaultlink + ct + ".gif";
                    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += Wc_DownloadFileCompleted;
                    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(currentLink), @"d:\test.gif");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                GenerateRadarLinks();
            }
        }
```

The method RoundDown

```
DateTime RoundDown(DateTime date, TimeSpan interval)
        {
            return new DateTime(date.Ticks / interval.Ticks *
                interval.Ticks);
        }
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your RoundDown method, or really the requirement of using it multiple times. Why don't you just decrement your dateTime minutes by five instead of continuously trying to round to the next number divisible by five (which is going to fail because your input will already be divisible by 5 after the first time, resulting in no change)?

also, using -5 in this context should make no difference since RoundDown multiplies interval by itself, so (-5) * (-5) = +25 anyways

Comment: @ShrimpPerator First the reason for trying to round down and not changing the minutes each time on my own by minus 5 is because if for example the first time the DateTime.Now is 13:49 I must first change it to 13:45 then I can minus 5 on my own each time but at least the first time I must round it down because the link I need to test the time in the minutes must be 5 or 0 like 14:45 or 13:30 or 12:20 so maybe I need to round it down only at the first time and then minus 5 the minutes on my own if there is error. I will try to do it.

Comment: @ShrimpPerator The reason for trying multiple times to download is because I don't know what is the working link at the site I know only part of the link but not what is the date time part of the link.  that is why I'm doing tests until I find the correct currentLink working link.

Comment: @ShrimpPerator A built link in my code should be like this for example : https://Radar_202110151650.gif but because I don't know yet if the formatted date time is the right one I want to keep round down the minutes each time by 5 until the download will be fine and then I know that this is the correct link.  So if for example this link is not working the next link should be : https://Radar_202110151645.gif and then https://Radar_202110151640.gif  and so on down the minutes by 5. this is the tests I need to do to find the working link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `roundDown` won't work once you arrived at a date, which is already at some multiple of 5 minutes. Imagine the following:

Assuming integer division `103 / 5 * 5` will give `20 * 5` thus `100` as expected. But in the next iteration you then have `100 / 5 * 5` will again give `100`, because
`100 / 5 == 103 / 5 == 20` (with integer division).

So for this to work, you will need to decrement the time by at least one tick, so it's not a multiple of 5 minutes anymore.

```
DateTime RoundDown(DateTime date, TimeSpan interval) {
  return new DateTime((date.Ticks - 1)/ interval.Ticks * interval.Ticks);
}
```

I personally would use the `RoundDown` method only once to generate the first timestamp that is a multiple of 5. For all following requests, I'd just take the current timestamp and decrement it by 5 minutes.

```
//inital timestamp
current = RoundDown(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-5));

//in the error handler
current = current.AddMinutes(-5);
```

Comment: or round once, then just decrement by five minutes to be more efficient.

Comment: @ShrimpPerator thanks for the comment. That's what I just updated my post to ...

Comment: must've just missed the edit :) btw. you could just use 5 for the TimeSpan.FromMinutes. The negative will be multiplied away anyways

Comment: @ShrimpPerator right. I just copied that line from OP's question